# How to delete everything between two :'s, but not if between {}'s?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a text file like this:

```
This is {an example} of : some of the: text.
This is yet {another : example :} of some of the text.
:This: is :still :yet another {:example:} of :some text:.
```

I need to delete any text found inside any `:`'s, including the `:`'s, but not if they fall inside a pair of `{` and `}`.

- Anything between a `{` and `}` is safe, including `:`'s.
- Anything not between a `{` and `}` but found between `:` and `:` is deleted.
- The `:`'s found outside `{` and `}` are all deleted.

The output would look like this:

```
This is {an example} of  text.
This is yet {another : example :} of some of the text.
 is yet another {:example:} of .
```

- There is only one set of braces per line.
- The paired braces are never split across lines.
- There could be any number of `:`'s on the line, inside or outside the braces.
- `:`'s always come in pairs.

How can I delete everything between colons, including the colons themselves, but not when protected by braces?

My best attempt so far is to use `awk -F"{" '{ print $1 }' > file1.txt`, `awk -F"{" '{ print $2 }' > file2.txt`, etc. to split the lines around the braces into different, run `sed` on the specific files to remove the parts, but not on the files containing the data inside the braces, then to assemble it back together with `paste`, but this solution is far too complicated.

Comment: It always helps a lot if you show the *real* data. Otherwise answers become a series of to-and-fro messages that say *"well, in the actual data I have"*

Comment: Can the braces `{ .. }` be nested?

Comment: No, they are never nested. Exactly one `{` and one `}` per line.

Answer (score 2):

This will do as you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {
  local $/;
  <DATA>;
};

my @parts = split m/ ( \{ [^{}]* \} ) /x, $data;

for (@parts) {
  s/ : [^:]* : //gx unless /^\{/;
}

print @parts, "\n";


__DATA__
This is {an example} of : some of the: text.
This is yet {another : example :} of some of the text.
:This: is :still :yet another {:example:} of :some text:.
```

**output**

```
This is {an example} of  text.
This is yet {another : example :} of some of the text.
 is yet another {:example:} of .
```

Comment: Nice +1. Do you not trust `.*?` ?

Comment: @glennjackman: It's a habit - a good one I hope - that speeds up the execution of regex pattern matching. The idea is that with `/ \{ .*? \} /x` the regex engine has to repeatedly try zero or more characters until it finds one that is followed by a closing brace `}`. With `/ \{ [^}]* \} /x` it just skims through all the characters that aren't a closing brace. No, it won't make any difference for many Perl programs, but it will always be faster

Comment: you guys had made a simple thing too complex, as long as you know how Perl regex alternation works, it is just a simple regex issue.

Comment: @lihao: I am using a regex. And I know how regex alternation works, although it's irrelevant here. What do you mean?

Comment: @Borodin, if you read the book 'Mastering Regular Expressions' by J. Friedl. this question is just a very typical one.

Comment: @lihao: That book is on my shelves and I have read it several times. I don't think there's anything in there that's significantly simpler than my solution, but I could be wrong. I suggest you write your own answer so that we can see what you mean.

Comment: @Borodin, I already added last night.

Answer (score 2):

this is simple, try the following:

```
perl -pe 's/({[^{}]*})|:[^:]*:/$1/g' file
```

all texts inside { } are saved in $1 and thus skipped:)

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

while (<>) {
    my @chars = split //;
    foreach my $c (@chars) {
        if ($c eq "{" .. $c eq "}") {
            print "$c";
        } elsif ($c eq ":" ... $c eq ":") {
        }
        else {
            print "$c";
        }
    }
}
```

or put more succinctly:

```
while (<>) {
    print grep {/\{/ .. /\}/ or not /:/ ... /:/} split //;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting braces and colons:

```
perl -ne '
    $b = $c = 0;
    for $char (split //) {
        $b++ if $char eq "{"; 
        $b-- if $char eq "}";
        if ($b > 0) { 
            print $char; 
        }
        else {
            if ($c == 0 and $char eq ":") {
                $c++;
            }
            else {
                print $char if $c == 0;
                $c-- if $c == 1 and $char eq ":";
            }
        }
    }
' <<END
This is {an example} of : some of the: text.
This is yet {another : example :} of some of the text.
:This: is :still :yet another {:example:} of :some text:.
END
```

```
This is {an example} of  text.
This is yet {another : example :} of some of the text.
 is yet another {:example:} of .
```

Comment: -1 That is the one-liner with the most lines that I ever remember seeing.

Comment: Is that a problem? Is it unreadable? Or does it offend your sense of style?